# Was my comment deleted? (1)

Tags: discussion

If I am not mistaken I had made a comment under the question [*Why are pilgrimages or tours to other than the three mosques prohibited?*](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/10110/3487) which I can't seem to find now. Was it deleted? And if so why?

I don't think it was *rude or offensive*, *not constructive* or *too chatty*.